/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by myservice)
in docker file after changing the go version from 1.18 to 1.22, we got below error while deploying the image for my service.
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by myservice)
the build server go version is still 1.18. however, it did not throw any error while creating image, but during deployment it throws.
here is the content of my dockerfile
# Stage 1: building the base image
FROM docker-5gc.cz.intinfra.com/platform/basecentos7fat:202209020713 as base
ARG INSTALL_GCC_LIBS
ARG COMPONENTS_URL=/common/tools
COPY ${COMPONENTS_URL}/busybox /usr/bin/busybox
# End Stage 1


# Stage 2: build application
FROM golang:1.22 AS builder

# Create the working dir
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod 0777 script_myservice.sh

# Build
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o myservice .
# End Stage 2

# Stage 3: Create alpine builder image to copy netstat
FROM golang:1.22-alpine3.19 AS builder_alpine
RUN apk add --update
RUN apk add --upgrade tcpdump
RUN apk add --upgrade strace
RUN apk add --upgrade vim
#RUN ldd --version
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
# End Stage 3

# Stage 4 Prepare container
FROM docker-5gc.cz.intinfra.com/platform/distroless/base:26634bc62b91 AS dev-env
USER root

# install busybox
WORKDIR /opt/bin
COPY --from=base /usr/bin/busybox /bin/busybox
SHELL ["/bin/busybox", "sh", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
RUN busybox --install -s /usr/bin
RUN busybox --install -s /bin
RUN echo -e "#!/bin/sh\n\n/bin/sh \"\$@\"\n" >> /bin/bash
RUN chmod +x /bin/bash
SHELL [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]

# prepare working dir
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/mmyservice .
COPY --from=builder /app/script_myservice.sh .
# Dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs && mkdir -p /usr/lib64 && mkdir -p /usr/sbin
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/bin/tcpdump /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/bin/strace /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/bin/top /usr/bin/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /go/bin/dlv /app/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /lib/libcrypto.so.3 /lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1 /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/libdw.so.1 /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/libelf.so.1 /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /lib/libz.so.1 /lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/libfts.so.0 /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5 /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1 /usr/lib/
COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6 /usr/lib/
#COPY --from=builder_alpine /usr/lib/liblua-5.3.so.0 /usr/lib/

COPY common/tools/ip /usr/sbin/
COPY common/tools/bin/centos/jq /usr/bin/
COPY common/tools/lib/centos/libjq.so.1.0.4 /usr/lib64/
COPY common/tools/lib/centos/libonig.so.5.0.0 /usr/lib64/
RUN cd /usr/lib64 && \
    ln -s libjq.so.1.0.4 libjq.so.1 && \
    ln -s libonig.so.5.0.0 libonig.so.5

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
# End Stage 4

any inputs, would be great help

Because of the compiler change, your executable now depends on libc and you don't copy libc into the final image.

so you mean go 1.18 is not dependent on libc and go 1.22 does? if so what is the solution for it? please suggest

This Dockerfile is fascinating for having four build stages with four entirely different Linux distributions.  In the final stage where you're manually copying binaries and C shared libraries into a "distroless" image, I'd consider this a Linux-expert-level setup; this might be much easier to do if you consistently used either a Debian or Alpine base across all of the stages, and used that distribution's package manager (apt-get or apk respectively) to install binaries.
